# Does $(I-BB^\dagger)C=0$ hold for a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $G = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T &C \end{pmatrix}$ with $C \preceq B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, pseudoinverse, schur-complement

Given a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix

$$ G = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B^T &C \end{pmatrix}$$

where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are not invertible, and $C\preceq B$, does the following equality hold?

$$ \left( I - B B^\dagger \right) C = 0 $$

Or, equivalently, does the following hold?

$$ C = B B^\dagger C$$

where $B^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $B$.

I already know from [here](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1637&context=cis_papers) (Theorem 4.3) that we have

$$(I-AA^\dagger)B=0 \text{ and } (I-CC^\dagger)B^T=0$$ (we have it even without $C \preceq B$).

Edit : user 1551 proposed a direct counter-example to my proposition, I realized that it missed an assumption from my application: $C \preceq B$.

Comment: Consider $B=0\ne C$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, you made me realize that I forgot an assumption in addition to the symmetric positive semidefiniteness of G, I have $C \preceq B$.

Comment: It yields $(I-BB^\dagger)C = (I-(2C)(2C)^\dagger)C = (C-CC^\dagger C) = 0$

Comment: May I ask you details about the implications : 
 1) $G \succeq 0$ and $C \preceq  B \Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(B) = \mathcal{C}(C)$.
 2) $\mathcal{C}(B) = \mathcal{C}(C) \Rightarrow BB^\dagger = CC^\dagger$
Thank you for your help

Comment: @user1551 is the implication 2) related to the fact that $BB^\dagger$ is a projector onto the column space of $B$, hence, if the column space of $B$ and $C$ are the same then the projectors are the same i.e. $BB^\dagger = CC^\dagger$ ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I assume $B=B^T$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $G\succeq0$, if $Cx=0$, then
$$
x^TBABx+2tx^TB^2x
=\pmatrix{x^TB&tx^T}\pmatrix{A&B\\ B&C}\pmatrix{Bx\\ tx}\ge0
$$
for every real number $t$. Therefore $\|Bx\|_2^2=x^TB^2x$ must be zero and in turn $Bx=0$. Hence $\ker(C)\subseteq\ker(B)$.

On the other hand, if $Bx=0$, then $-x^TCx=x^T(B-C)x\ge0$. Hence $Cx=0$ and $\ker(B)\subseteq\ker(C)$.

Thus $\ker(C)=\ker(B)$ and the orthogonal projections onto them coincide. That is, $I-CC^+=I-BB^+$. It follows that $(I-BB^+)C=(I-CC^+)C=0$.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !